# Rails 5 - How to fix Middleware/Rack/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, routes, newrelic

In rails 5, I am using NewRelic to monitor the application. In newrelic, instantly I am getting `Middleware/Rack/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call` as most time consuming. I don't know why this issue is happening.

In routes.rb,

```
devise_for :admins
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
scope :api do
scope :v1 do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    passwords: 'users/passwords'
  }
  get 'confirm_user_email', to: 'user_emails#confirm_email', as: :confirm_user_email
  get 'forgot_password', to: 'landing_page#forgot_password'
  post 'send_invitation', to: 'users#send_invitation', as: :send_invitation
 end
end
unless Rails.env.production?
  mount LetterOpenerWeb::Engine, at: '/letter_opener'
end

require 'sidekiq/web'
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
get "*path" => "home#index"

mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: well, have you looked into your router?

Comment: Yes. And question has updated too.

Comment: @ShruthiR Did you find a solution to it? I am also facing the same issue. Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, even I didn't get the solution.

Comment: I've got a feeling its to do with ActionCable. I've got the same and I'm using ActionCable for a live update page.

Answer (score 0):

Please move the `newrelic_rpm` to the bottom of the Gemfile. This is required as when server starts, ruby agent should load up first and then the new relic agent so that the transaction calls can be routed through new relic agent so that new relic captures the transactions.